# Fetch data based on query string value in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, query-string

My `getInitialProps` makes two requests.

Now I would like to do one more if the query params key is legal person. For example, if the URL is `https://www.example.com.br/?legal-person`, fetch data in a URL, else fetch data in another URL.

What I could see is that Next.js has the query object that returns this, I even tried using an if, but it didn't work as below. It shows the error:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'ParsedUrlQuery' and 'string' have no overlap.

But I also don't know if what I tried to do that way would be the best way.

```js
CompareLoans.getInitialProps = async ({query}) => {

  const loanTypesRes = await fetch(`${process.env.BFF_API}/api/loan-types/`)
  const loanTypesResJson = await loanTypesRes.json()

  if (query === 'legal-person') {
   const initialLoans = await fetch(`${process.env.BFF_API}/api/loans-legal-person/initial`)
   const initialLoansJson = await initialLoans.json()

  } else {
   const initialLoans = await fetch(`${process.env.BFF_API}/api/loans/initial`)
   const initialLoansJson = await initialLoans.json()
  }
  
  return {loanTypes: loanTypesResJson, initialLoans: initialLoansJson}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions `query` is an object of type `ParsedUrlQuery`, it's not a string you can directly compare to `'legal-person'`.

What you could do is check that `legal-person` is present in the `query` object instead.

```js
CompareLoans.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
    // Custom logic here

    if (Object.keys(query).includes('legal-person')) {
        // Do something when `legal-person` is in the query string
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }

    // More custom logic here
}
```